# How can I call Angular's simple field filter in a controller?

Tags: angularjs, filter, controller

I can do a simple filter like such:

```
Name Filter: <input ng-model="MyFilter.Name" />
Age Filter: <input ng-model="MyFilter.Age" />

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="thing in Things | Filter:MyFilter">
    {{thing.Name}} {{thing.Age}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can also call my own filters in my controller:

```
$scope.Things = $filter("MyCustomFilter")($scope.AllThings, params);
```

These both work fine, but I would like to move the first, simple filter into the controller as well, to do something like this:

```
$scope.Things = $filter("MyCustomFilter")($scope.AllThings, params);
$scope.Things = $filter("Filter")($scope.Things, $scope.MyFilter);
```

The idea being to call my custom filter first and then call the simple, built-in filter on the results. I want to do this in the controller because I have other code that needs to know the list of filtered item, so leaving it in the html is not an option.

The above code throws an exception, complaining about a circular reference.

What is the proper way to use Angular's simple filter in a controller?

Thank you.

Comment: If you have an exception, ALWAYS post the exact and complete exception error and stack trace in your question.